# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL?

Tags: magento, soap

Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from         'http://x.x.x.x/magento/api/soap/?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found in

We used SOAP api version 1 in magento working in local perfectly (windows environment) and not in server (Linux).

PHP soap and xml-rpc in enabled in server.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you have an error in some xml somewhere, or your not getting the wsdl file returned. If you visit the wsdl URL manually do you actually get the wsdl xml definitions? Check this first. If so, run it through an xml validator to check it's valid. From the fact it's looking for an '<' tag, I suspect you are not getting the wsdl file returned, but an error instead so check your magento error logs. Also, from memory, I think you might need to setup a host entry on the server to your site as well, I have seen this before and that has resolved it. Magento's soap controller initiates a connection to the wsdl file when you make a request and it might not be able to resolve to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Magento are you using, but there is a [SOAP patch for Magento 1.9.x](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-patches-soap)